# Создание кастомного checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Как создать кастомный вариант checkbox в виде кнопки?
Был бы благодарен примеру и краткими объяснениями

[image: обычное состояние]
[image: Нажатая]

Comment: как вариант - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445409/how-to-create-a-custom-wpf-xaml-style-for-check-box-images

Comment: Так всё-таки WinForms или WPF? Это слишком разные технологии. Вероятно, стоит задать два отдельных вопроса по каждой из них.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov тогда лучше winform

Comment: А я бы на вашем месте лучше бы посмотрел в сторону WPF. Там такое в пару стилей сделать можно. ИМХО легче... Но все же да, стоит явно указать то, на чем разрабатываете и убрать лишнюю метку у вопроса.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ был бы и не против и вариант WPF расмотреть, но все же winforms легче просто

Comment: Тут я с вами не соглашусь. WPF от части создан для того, что бы как раз и упростить определенные аспекты программирования. Особенно!! это касается дизайна. Хотите хороший вид приложения - лучше учите WPF, мой вам совет...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В WPF как по мне такое сделать намного легче, ведь для нас становиться доступен XAML с его стилями и другими "плюшками".

К примеру нам надо сделать первое изображение. Из чего оно состоит?

- Фон с закругленными углами
  В WPF для этого отлично подойдет Border c установленным CornerRadius.
- Простой текст определенного цвета.

Ну так давайте напишем простенький стиль!
*Я не буду тут реализовывать все, а просто покажу пример того, как можно поступить*

1. Сделаем заготовку для нашего стиля.
   У него мы зададим Key, что бы не применялся ко всем ChecBox, а только к тем, которые нам нужны. Также укажем тип, ну и внутри зададим один Setter, который будет переопределять Template нашего элемента:

   ```
   <Style x:Key="MyCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">

               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
   ```
2. Добавим дополнительные Setter (цвет, размер текста и др.).
   Setter - это по сути то, что стандартно будет задано элементу, их спокойно можно переопределить после у каждого элемента по отдельности.

   ```
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFA4CE36"/>
   <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="100"/>
   <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="100"/>
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
   <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
   ```
3. Теперь время дошло до переопределения самого шаблона. В ControlTemplate создадим Border с нашим содержимом внутри.

   ```
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
       <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
               Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
               BorderBrush="#33000000"
               BorderThickness="1"
               CornerRadius="25"
               Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

           <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                             Focusable="False" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                             RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                             SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
       </Border>
   </ControlTemplate>
   ```

*ContentPresenter - это как раз то, что будет задано через Content элементу (либо его дочерний элемент).*

4. Ну теперь остается сделать так, что бы было понятно, поставили ли мы "галку" или нет. Для этого существует такая вещь, как "Триггеры". В моем случае сделаю просто, если `IsChecked = true` - делаем текст белый.

   ```
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
       </Trigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   ```

Весь стиль в итоге получился такой:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFA4CE36"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                        BorderBrush="#33000000"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="25"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                      Focusable="False" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Осталось прицепить данный стиль на нужный элемент:

```
<CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource MyCheckBox}" Content="1" />
```

И результат:

[image: Result]

В этом примере много чего нету, но основную суть того, как редактировать элементы на WPF думаю вы поймете. Удачи в изучение!

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но хотел бы уточнить, как правильно изменять через ControlTemplate.Triggers, пробывал добавлять <Setter.Value> и <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">, чтобы редактировать через Border, но что то не получается...

Comment: @ВикторПрокопенко Немного не понял вопроса, что вы хотите и где отредактировать?

Comment: как в ControlTemplate.Triggers добавить Border для дальнейшего изменения? Если проще, то не разобрался как в менять состояние чекбокса когда он чекнутый...

Comment: @ВикторПрокопенко В Triggers находятся **только** тригеры, некоторые скажем так, события, которые мы отлавливаем и изменяем нужный параметр. Вы не можете создать там объект, не правильно это будет. Все объекты находятся в ControlTemplate , не ControlTemplate.Triggers! Если вам надо изменить только определенный элемент, то в ControlTemplate задайте ему имя (x:Name) и в триггерах используйте (<Setter TargetName=...).

Comment: <Setter TargetName="\CornerRadius" CornerRadius="10"/> ? также думал это поможет <Setter Propetry="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>, но безрезультатно

Comment: @ВикторПрокопенко Вы забыли указать еще `Property` - что меняем и `Value` - на что меняем. То есть должно быть что то вроде `<Setter TargetName="myBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>`. Ну и у элемента border указать `x:Name="myBorder"` надо не забыть. Вообще в этом очень классно помогают подсказки студии, советую следовать им!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ EvgeniyZ довольно содержательный.
Дополню трэд своим примером с базовой анимацией.

Используем:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <CheckBox Template="{StaticResource CustomCheckBox}" Background="Green" Foreground="Red"/>
    <CheckBox  Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource CustomCheckBox}" Background="Aqua" Foreground="DarkBlue" Content="Hello world"/>

    <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource CustomCheckBox2}" Background="Red"/>
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource CustomCheckBox2}" Background="Red" Content="Custom checkbox 2"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тип 1:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomCheckBox" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Checkbox_True">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Checkbox_False">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Viewbox Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30" Fill="White"/>
                <Rectangle Width="25" Height="25" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                <Rectangle Width="18" Height="18" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="White"/>
                <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Width="14" Height="14" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Checkbox_False_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Checkbox_False}"/>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Checkbox_True_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Checkbox_True}"/>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Тип 2:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomCheckBox2" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Checkbox2_True">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00000000"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="Black"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Checkbox2_False">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="#00000000"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Viewbox Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30" Fill="White"/>
                <Rectangle Width="25" Height="25" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                <Rectangle Width="18" Height="18" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="White"/>
                <Path x:Name="path" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="1.5">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="10 15" EndPoint="15.5 22"/>
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="15 22" EndPoint="20 10"/>
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Checkbox2_False_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Checkbox2_False}"/>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Checkbox2_True_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Checkbox2_True}"/>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

я как то с делал стили

```
<Style x:Key="MainStyleCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
      Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <BulletDecorator Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Border Width="30" Height="28" Name="Border" Background="#FF595959" Cursor="Hand" BorderBrush="#FF484848" CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="1">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>
                                </Border.Effect>
                                <Border Name="ChechedBorder" Width="24" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Height="22" BorderBrush="DimGray" Background="#FF5A5A5A"></Border>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                </BulletDecorator>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="ChechedBorder" Property="Background"  Value="LightGreen"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ChechedBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF484848" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"  Value="Green"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ChechedBorder" Property="Background"  Value="#FFD6586A"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ChechedBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFA80808" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"  Value="#FFA02323"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ChechedBorder" Property="Background"  Value="#FF595959"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ChechedBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="black" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"  Value="#FF484848"/>

                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ChechedBorder" Property="Background"  Value="#FF30462F"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ChechedBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF1F1F1F" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"  Value="Green"/>

                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

красно зеленый с CheckBox и становится до кучи серым при не активности, 
а есть еще on/off

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle2"
           TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
      Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <BulletDecorator Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Border x:Name="Border"
                                    Width="32"
                                    Height="28"
                                    CornerRadius="2"
                                    BorderThickness="1" 
                                    BorderBrush="#FF242424"
                                    Cursor="Hand" Background="#FFDEDEDE">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>
                                </Border.Effect>
                                <Label Name="BooleanContent2" 
                                           Content="Off" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                                           VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            </Border>
                            <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                       />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True" >
                        <Trigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent2" Property="Content" Value="On"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FF60A3ED"/>
                        </Trigger.Setters>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Trigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent2" Property="Content" Value="Off"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FFDEDEDE"/>
                        </Trigger.Setters>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```